# Cannot use free space in filesystem

Tags: centos, disk-usage

I want to install a program but it says that there is not enough free disk space more than 11 GB although there is.

df -h shows:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_mach-lv_root
                       50G   39G   11G  79% /
tmpfs                 942M  540K  942M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   55M  406M  12% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_mach-lv_home
                      176G   27G  141G  17% /home
```

df -i shows:

```
Filesystem             Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_resyslab-lv_root
                      3264000 583552  2680448   18% /
tmpfs                  220064     16   220048    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              128016     46   127970    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_resyslab-lv_home
                     11714560  12254 11702306    1% /home
```

Also the system monitor shows:
[image]

Command & Program output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add a screen from your command and program output to your post for more help.

Comment: Try df -i to show inode usage.

Comment: I've added what you want.

Comment: You are trying to install in `/opt/Xlinks`, which has 11GB free( /opt belong to / filessytem)

try to install under `/home/XLinks` which has 141 Gb free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information reported by your various tools are consistent. There is approximately 151Gb free on your disks, among which 141Gb for the `/home` directory and 11Gb for the rest of the system. What happens is that you program must install somewhere in `/opt` which is not under the same logical partition as `/home` where there is room but under the root partition when there is only 11Gb left.

Comment: I don't know how it happened or why CentOS set the directories in this way. Can I resize the amount of disk space assigned to directories?

Comment: I will try to use system-config-lvm to resize the logical  volumes.

Comment: This is one of the reasons LVM is great, the risk of breaking things when resizing is reduced. Still, be careful and back things up before...